# Is there a book of logic by god , god giving reasons?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, creation

God talking about why did he create universe particularly why? Did god ever give his discourse on reason, why did he not create everything peaceful? God talking by logic, just pure reasoning?

Comment: Brahma Sutras states, quoting scriptural sources, that it is His sport. This is a duplicate question. Multiple questions. Please read forum rules

Comment: Is it written by brahma? Do we have any rational proof?

Comment: What do you mean by Rational Sir?

Comment: Based on reason, able to use logical thought rather than emotions, some scientific evidence or you can show it to me? @Rāmachandra

Comment: Nope buddy sorry to disappoint you!

Comment: Is playing with people's lives a sport?@SwamiVishwananda